# Identify request's page origin in ServiceWorker

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

In a `ServiceWorker`'s `onfetch` handler I want to be able to identify what page a `Request` is coming from.  For example, if I have 2 pages that both request `/resource.js`, and this request is passed to the service worker (the `onfetch` handler is called with a `FetchEvent`), how do I tell if it is one instance of a page requesting `/resource.js` twice, or 2 different pages requesting `/resource.js`?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible. The original poster seems to have already found and commented on https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/issues/723, but for the record, that's where it's currently being discussed in the service worker specification.

Once there's some agreement on the specification, you should expect browsers that support service workers to add in the functionality over time.

Comment: thanks for the response, nice to have some confirmation

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `event.request.referrer` to identify the page from which request originates.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/referrer

Comment: unfortunately this won't let me distinguish between 2 tabs open to the same page.